# XNA window maximized with task bar visible C#

Tags: c#, xna

I have this code which makes my game window to look maximised with the taskbar visible which is just what I need.

```
    protected override void Initialize()
    {    
        IntPtr hWnd = this.Window.Handle;
        var control = System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle(hWnd);
        var form = control.FindForm();
        form.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        form.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Normal;
        form.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0,-1); // doesnt seem to make any diffrence when X or Y = anything but 0
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height-1;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width;
        graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
        base.Initialize();
    }
```

The problem is that there is a small 1 pixel gap right above my game which I tried to get rid of by lifting the game window by the `form.Location(0,-1)`, but it doesn't move the window at all. Now, if i get rid of the `.CurrentDisplayMode.Height-1;` to just `Height`, then the game goes to fullscreen hiding the Task bar!

Comment: Do want it to be _actually_ maximized or do you just want it to _look_ maximized? Because there's an easy way to actually maximize the window.

Comment: @Lemoncreme, its same as if you press the F11 key on your keyboard, the browser goes to full screen and then back to normal with taskbar visible. Thats what i have working, but the bad thing is that it only works with CurrentDisplayMode.Height-1. If i remove the -1 statement, then even with FormWindowState.Normal the program still remains in full screen closing the taskbar.